# Reflection angle cg unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, cg

I have a plane with a cg shader on it that tells the plane to reflect a cube map. This line tells how it needs to reflect the cube map:

float3 reflectDir = reflect(viewDirection,v.normalWorld);

- normal world is the normal direction

I want the reflection to be 0% if you look right at the normal and 100 % if you look at the normal from the side, how can I archieve this? Now I made an illustration of what I want:

[image]

Comment: Multiply reflectivity by dot(normal, -viewDirection) assuming both are normalized?

Comment: Okay, so I tried that but the reflection became 0 so then I tried to put an intensity on it like this  `code float3 reflectDir = pow(dot(v.normalWorld, -viewDirection),_Reflection) * reflect(viewDirection,v.normalWorld); `  and I found out that its reversed. Its 100% at the top and 0% at the bottom how can I reverse that? And yes, they are both normalized.

Comment: I mean you should multiply the reflection contribution (i.e. colour) and not the reflection direction. I assume you use this direction for a lookup? The dot product would be a factor in how much you use the value you've just looked up. Perhaps show the whole relevant shader.

Comment: @Bart - no, that would give "1" when he's looking right at it and "0" when he's looking perpendicular to it.  The "magnitude" of the cross product of "viewdirection" and "normal" unit vectors will give him the proper linear variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reflectPercent = Vector3.Cross(viewDirection.normalized, normalDirection.normalized).magnitude;
```

Dot product is wrong - it is the *magnitude of projection* of a vector on another vector.

Although you could use

```
reflectPercent = Abs(1-Abs(Vector3.Dot(viewDirection.normalized, normalDirection.normalized)));
```